# Audit email in Exchange 2007

Tags: exchange-2007, outlook-2007

I'm a developer who's having to stand in as a sysadmin and I've been asked to make the contents of an inbox available to a users manager without informing the user.

We're running Exchange 2007 (pre-installed with SBS 2008). All clients are Outlook 2007.

I haven't been able to find much information for doing this in Exchange 2007 through Google - I've tried going to the exchange server, finding the user in "exchange directory users and computers" and in the permissions tab, I can see that domain admins (ie me) have full control for the account.

What I'm a little unclear on is how to actually view the inbox - I've tried adding a new mail profile (for myself - testing) which has the user in questions' email address but it prompts me for credentials when retrieving server settings (and mine don#t seem to be sufficient).

Would someone please be kind enough to point me at the idiot's guide or similar?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can grant access to a mailbox as described [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa996343(EXCHG.80).aspx). Basically you just assing mroe users to have logon permissions to the mailbox.

Comment: Be aware of the legal ramifications of doing this, as these kinds of things often have legal impacts.  The user has more access than just inspecting the mailbox contents by doing that.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to grant the manager access to the users mailbox by doing the following:

1. open Exchange Management Console
2. Expand Recipient Configuration
3. Click Mailbox
4. Right Click the User and "Manager Full Access Permission"
5. Click add, find the user and hit OK, then click manage and finsih.

You will now need to open an additional mailbox in Outlook you can do this by going into account properties in Outlook opening the existing users account, going into option and adding the additional mailbox in there.

Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: The reason you were asked for credentials is the mailbox is authenticated against the windows logon, when you attempt to access someone elses mailbox when you dont have appropriate permissions you are asked to provide account details for someone that does.